# Why post main effect being subsumed into the time fixed effects

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

In the DD equation, I have Treat indicator and Post indicator. The model also includes state fixed effects and year fixed effects. Is it necessary to omit Post variable (thus only Treat and Treat*Post)?

The paper said, "Post main effect being subsumed into the time fixed effects."

I am always confused on this point.

The DD model is:
$$Y_{ist}=\beta_0+\beta_1Treat_{ist}+\beta_2Treat_{ist}*Post_t+\gamma'X_{ist}+\rho'C_{st}+\delta_s+\phi_t+\epsilon_{ist}$$

where the outcome $Y_{ist}$ is an indicator equal to one if individual i living in state s who is surveyed in year t is on leave from work in the survey reference week and zero otherwise. (This paper is on paid family leave policy.)

The dummy variable $Treat_{ist}$ is equal to one for California fathers of infants;

$Post_t$ is an indicator equal to one if the individual is surveyed in 2005 or later. (2005 is the first year of the policy.)

The vector $X_{ist}$ contains the following individual-level indicator variables: father's age in bins, race,,,,(omit here)

vector $C_{st}$: state-year controls to account for labor market conditions and other state-specific factors affecting the decision to work: unemployment rate, poverty rate,,,,(omit here)

State and year fixed effects are captured by $\delta_s$ and $\phi_t$, respectively, with the $Post_t$ main effect being subsumed into the time fixed effects.

Comment: Is treatment at state level?

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, do you also have two periods (pre/post) and two groups (treatment/control), where all treated units receive treatment at the same time?

Comment: treatment has ist subscript, thus it is at individual level.

Comment: Yes, it is a standard DD model. From the model, two periods are before 2005 and after 2005. The two groups are CA fathers and non-CA fathers. The policy was in effect in 2005 in CA.

Answer (score 2):

In most difference-in-differences (DD) applications, the data is 'aggregated up' to a higher level such as the state. Though I have no problem with this specification, you may also have a situation that lends itself to *triple* differences, especially if the policy was adopted state-wide and only affects fathers *within* state *s*. But I digress.

> In the DD equation, I have Treat indicator and Post indicator. The model also includes state fixed effects and year fixed effects. Is it necessary to omit Post variable (thus only Treat and Treat*Post)?

No. In fact, most software packages will invariably drop the post-treatment indicator as it is collinear with the *time* fixed effects. Software will automatically attempt estimation of the constituent terms of your interaction (i.e., $Treat_{ist} \times Post_{t}$). But, due to presence of *time* effects in this setting, $Post_{t}$ is dropped. It is worth noting that the *ordering* of the variables matters with respect to estimation. In R, for example, suppose you specified the fixed effects *first* (i.e., separate dummies for states *and* years) and then specified the interaction. As a consequence of the formulaic ordering of the predictors, R will automatically omit the post-treatment dummy. Nothing changes, however. The coefficient on your interaction term *is* your treatment effect.

Now, suppose you specified the interaction first, *and then* threw in your dummies. As a consequence of the year fixed effects being specified *after* the interaction, R *must* drop one *additional* year dummy to allow for the estimation of the post-treatment dummy. Put differently, in addition to the normal procedure of omitting one year dummy, a *second* year dummy is removed from the model matrix so the coefficient on $Post_{t}$ may be estimated. Again, this will not affect the identification of your treatment effect.

> The paper said, "Post main effect being subsumed into the time fixed effects." I am always confused on this point.

This is correct. The *year* fixed effects will absorb a time dummy indexing your post-treatment years. Despite this, your treatment effect will not change. The post-treatment variable is a linear combination of some of the columns in your data frame (i.e., year effects). Admittedly, this is difficult to visualize without looking at a data frame with the fixed effects appended.

To demonstrate this explicitly, I will simulate a data frame in R. It is difficult with three-levels and a treatment implemented at the *i*-th level, but let's start with something very simple to visualize. Note, I will simulate a *panel* data frame, though your data should look a little different as you might be dealing with repeated cross-sections.

In my example, we have 2 individuals embedded within 2 states and we have observations on these individuals across 4 years. Treatment only affects specific individuals (i.e., fathers) *within* each state. The variable `treat` is 1 for California fathers, 0 otherwise. The `post` dummy indexes all $t$ years after the policy goes into effect in both treatment and control groups; treatment starts in 2005. In this example, we have a full set of *state* effects (i.e., dummies for *states*) and a full set of *year* effects (i.e., dummies for *years*).

Appending the year effects (e.g., `y_2004`, `y_2005`, and `y_2006`) to this data frame should help with your intuition. As indicated earlier, the `post` variable is a dummy 'turning on' in 2005 and 2006. If we inspect the last two columns of the data frame, it is evident that the post-treatment variable is a linear combination of *individual* post-treatment year dummies. In fact, the main effect for $Post_{t}$ is the sum of the last two year effects (i.e., `post = y_2005 + y_2006`). Thus, all of your predictors are *not* linearly *in*dependent. As a compromise for singularities, software drops your post (time) dummy in a DD equation. More precisely, if the interaction is specified *after* the inclusion of the fixed effects, then $Post_{t}$ *will* be dropped by software. I can't speak for all software packages, but order matters!

I hope this clears up any confusion.

```
# Three-Level Panel (i*s*t = 16 Total Observations)

 A tibble: 16 x 9
   state  year person treat  post state_fe y_2004 y_2005 y_2006
   <fct> <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 NY     2003 Mother     0     0        0      0      0      0
 2 NY     2004 Mother     0     0        0      1      0      0
 3 NY     2005 Mother     0     1        0      0      1      0
 4 NY     2006 Mother     0     1        0      0      0      1
 5 NY     2003 Father     0     0        0      0      0      0
 6 NY     2004 Father     0     0        0      1      0      0
 7 NY     2005 Father     0     1        0      0      1      0
 8 NY     2006 Father     0     1        0      0      0      1
 9 CA     2003 Mother     0     0        1      0      0      0
10 CA     2004 Mother     0     0        1      1      0      0
11 CA     2005 Mother     0     1        1      0      1      0
12 CA     2006 Mother     0     1        1      0      0      1
13 CA     2003 Father     1     0        1      0      0      0
14 CA     2004 Father     1     0        1      1      0      0
15 CA     2005 Father     1     1        1      0      1      0
16 CA     2006 Father     1     1        1      0      0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out today. Let's review the concept of Perfect multicollinearity first. Perfect multicollinearity occurs when two or more independent variables in a regression model exhibit a deterministic (perfectly predictable or containing no randomness) linear relationship. Suppose you have a model that $$Y_i=\beta_o+\beta_1X_{i1}+\beta_2X_{i2}+\epsilon_i$$ and
$$X_{i2}=\alpha_o+\alpha_1X_{i1}$$
By doing easy substitution, you then get $$Y_i=\beta_o+\beta_2\alpha_o+(\beta_1+\beta_2\alpha_1)X_{i1}+\epsilon_i$$

You can find that now the equation only contains $X_{i1}$. Obtaining individual regression coefficients (for example, $X_{i2}$) for every variable is impossible if you have perfect multicollinearity.

There are 2 cases in econometrics that could have collinearity: among each other, or with the fixed-effects. The above example is for the former case. Your questions is on the latter case.

Why the above example have collinearity problem? Because in the equation, some independent variable(s) can perfectly predictable other independent variable(s). Once I know $X_{i1}$, I can definitely know $X_{i2}$. That's what I say "perfectly predictable". Once you include fixed effects, then such "perfectly predictable" could happen.

In my example, the paper includes time (year) fixed effects, which is equivalent to you have a set of year dummy variables to denote every single year in your model. Thus, you can imagine there is one variable, say,  $X_{i1}$ means that whether this unit is year 2005. Once you know it is the year 2005, then you know whether this observation is post or before. Because Post is fixed within every-year level. This is exactly what I call "perfectly predictable". But if this variable is changing with each year, then there will be no problem at all. The take-away is Anything that does not vary within the levels (could be individual, time, etc.) is taken care of and cannot be included.

Comment: Good answer. But is this an answer to your own question?

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out today.